# Ember JS Routes, How can I load two model types on one route?

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

I'm trying to write an e-commerce style Ember App. I'm modelling it (this is an assignment and I figured it would be a great excuse to learn Ember.) https://www.humblebundle.com/store is sort of the model I'm going after.

I'd like to display two types of content on the index route - Promos, and Games, since they display differently.

```
Store.Router.map(function() {

  this.resource('promos', function(){

  });

  this.resource('games', function(){

  });

});
```

I presently redirect index to promos - But in reality, I'd like to have both promos and game render into their own named outlets. Are there any guides on doing this? So far, it seems like everything deals with making apps that have one concern at a time.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/ and http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

Comment: I'm using {{render "promos"}} and {{render "games"}} in the `index` template at the moment. Is that the expected workflow? Or am I supposed to do it through a Route?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`renderTemplate()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) on your route like this:

```
Store.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){

    return {
      games: ['checkmates', 'magic the gathering', 'flappy bird'],
      promos: ['1','42']
    };
  },

  renderTemplate:function(){
    this.render('games', { outlet: 'games' });
    this.render('promos', { outlet: 'promos' });
  }
});
```

JSBin here -- http://jsbin.com/jupet/2/edit

Comment: Thanks a ton. Maybe someone else can help me out here in making sure I have a complete understanding. Routes are for pages, not for data access? It's a legitimate thing to access data from one type, in another Route?

Comment: @BryanRayner Think of Routes as objects responsible what templates and how will be used to render particular model (models in your sophisticated case) and also what controller to use for model.

I thinks it's totally OK to access model from other route. They even have special [methods](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) for that.

Comment: So, to be very explicit about this, Routes tell the application and developer 'this is what happens when the browser is at this location'.   Model, for a Route, is 'This is what's needed by all this stuff I'm doing at this location.'

Comment: I have a follow up question. How would I assign a unique ArrayController to games, and promos, in your example?

Comment: @BryanRayner you can pass controller to [`renderTemplate()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) liko so: http://jsbin.com/jupet/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm currently doing things. The code works, though I'm not sure whether or not it's the 'right way'.

```
Store.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
 // Hook that runs when the controllers are being set up.
 setupController: function(controller, model) {

   this.controllerFor('promos').set('model', this.store.find('promo'));
   this.controllerFor('games').set('model', this.store.find('game'));

   controller.set('content', model);
 }
```

Then, in the index template:

```
{{render "promos"}}
{{render "games"}}
```

Things are working, and the GamesController and PromosController are hooking up to the right models.